# Removing extraneous div tags from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape text from a website and can't figure out how to remove an extraneous div tag. Code looks like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

team_urls = 
     ['http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/shape+of+you_21113143.html/',
   'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/thinking+out+loud_21083784.html',
   'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/photograph_21058341.html']

for url in team_urls:
     page = requests.get(url)
     soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

     for e in soup.find_all('br'):
         e.replace_with('\n')

     lyrics = soup.find(class_='dn')

     print(lyrics)
```

This is giving me an output of:

```
<div class="dn" id="content_h">The club isn't the best place...
```

I would like to remove the div tag.

Comment: You can get text from found div like “str = lyrics.text”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Full code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/shape+of+you_21113143.html/',
        'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/thinking+out+loud_21083784.html',
        'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/photograph_21058341.html']

for url in urls:
    page = requests.get(url)
    page.encoding = 'utf-8'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    div = soup.select_one('#content_h')

    for e in div.find_all('br'):
        e.replace_with('\n')

    lyrics = div.text
    print(lyrics)
```

Notice that sometimes the wrong encoding is used:

> I may be crazy donât mind me

That's why I set it manually: `page.encoding = 'utf-8'`. Fragment of the [requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.text) mentioning this situation:

> The encoding of the response content is determined based solely on HTTP headers, following RFC 2616 to the letter. If you can take advantage of non-HTTP knowledge to make a better guess at the encoding, you should set r.encoding appropriately before accessing this property.

Comment: Thanks. That did what I wanted it to do. One question though: why did the div = soup.select_one('#content_h') do what I had commissioned lyrics = soup.find(class_='dn') to do?

Comment: That's because `content_h` is the id of the element you want to target. [ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) is a unique identifier, so it's usually better to use it if you want to target one specific element. `#` is a CSS selector, you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. That's very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You could use regular expressions

```
import requests
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

team_urls = ['http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/shape+of+you_21113143.html/',
             'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/thinking+out+loud_21083784.html',
             'http://www.lyricsfreak.com/e/ed+sheeran/photograph_21058341.html']

for url in team_urls:
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    for e in soup.find_all('br'):
        e.replace_with('\n')

    lyrics = soup.find(class_='dn')
    cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, '', lyrics.text)

    print(cleantext)
```

Which will remove everything between the < and >

By using the special characters mentioned in the python docs

"

.
    (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.

*
    Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or more repetitions of the preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. ab* will match ‘a’, ‘ab’, or ‘a’ followed by any number of ‘b’s.

?
    Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding RE. ab? will match either ‘a’ or ‘ab’.

"

from https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: You don't need to use regex at all. `lyrics.text` is enough :P there is nothing that matches `<.*>` left in the string, therefore calling `re.sub` is unnecessary.